# Find matching numbers in an array and print result to new array

Tags: python, arrays

Trying to figure out why the code I have produced is not the answer to the following question:

Given two arrays, one with user inputs and another of correct inputs, return an array that denotes when the user input matches the correct input with the number 1, and incorrect inputs with -1.

My code below

```
newArr = []
def correct_stream(user, correct):
    for i in user:
        for j in correct:
            if i == j:
                newArr.append(1)
            else:
                newArr.append(-1)
                
            return newArr
```

Comment: What’s the issue you’re running into? Any errors you have questions about?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  You do this by tracing the operation with strategically-placed `print` statements.  See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.

Comment: I am going to guess that your return shouldn't be inside the for loops.

Comment: Just as a hint, your code has multiple problems.  The first debugging steps are your responsibility; we'll help if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Your `return` statement is inside of your second `for` loop and will only execute once.

```
newArr = []
def correct_stream(user, correct):
    for i in user:
        for j in correct:
            if i == j:
                newArr.append(1)
            else:
                newArr.append(-1)
                
            return newArr #this executes after the if statement runs only once, leading to an array with size 1
```

Python is built upon proper syntax, and while some aspects are flexible, indentation is strict. Brackets don't split apart scopes, indentation does.

```
newArr = []
def correct_stream(user, correct):
    for i in user:
        for j in correct:
            if i == j:
                newArr.append(1)
            else:
                newArr.append(-1)
                
    return newArr #this now executes after the whole for loop above is finished
```